# Google Maps API, problems showing InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

As shown in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq9vu/) The InfoWindow seems to have the problems showing the address and latlng. Not able to debug it myself, as I had somebody else build this for me. I am a n00b at JS and was trying to fix this error. This was a template taken from CoDrops and seems like everylink I found from the comments have similar issues.

[image: Maps InfoWindow]

```
    BGMap                   = (function() {
    var map,
        $mapEl      = $('#map'),
        address     = '5a Queen St, Wells, Somerset BA5 2DP',
        lat         = 51.2076068,
        lng         = -2.6486671,
        display     = false,

        showMap     = function() {
            hideMap();

            display         = true;

            var point       = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                mapOptions  = {
                    zoom                        : 18,
                    center                      : point,
                    mapTypeId                   : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                    mapTypeControl              : false,
                    panControl                  : true,
                    panControlOptions           : {
                        position    : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },
                    zoomControl                 : true,
                    zoomControlOptions          : {
                        style       : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                        position    : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },
                    streetViewControl           : true,
                    streetViewControlOptions    : {
                        position    : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    }
                };

            map             = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            //rotate 45 degrees (nicer view!)
            map.setTilt(45);

            resizeMap();

            var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth : 10}),   
                latlngStr       = address + "<br />LatLng: " + lat + " , " + lng + "<br />";

            coordInfoWindow.setContent(latlngStr);    
            coordInfoWindow.setPosition(point);    
            coordInfoWindow.open(map);

            BGImageController.fadeBG(false);
        },
        resizeMap   = function() {
            $mapEl.css({
                width   : $(window).width() + 'px',
                height  : $(window).height() + 'px'
            });
        },
        hideMap     = function() {
            display = false;
            $mapEl.empty();
        },
        active      = function() {
            return display;
        };

    return {
        showMap     : showMap,
        hideMap     : hideMap,
        active      : active,
        resizeMap   : resizeMap
    };
})(),
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following section of code

```
var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth : 10}),
```

Change the `maxWidth` property to a higher value (at least 100), or remove it, and you will see your address information.

Here is [the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq9vu/1/) showing a value of 120 for the `maxWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Main thing I can see here is this line:

```
var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth : 10})
```

You're saying the info window should be a maximum width of 10px. Set this to 100 or 150 and then you should see your data displaying.